# How to induce superposition from a collapsed quantum state?

Tags: quantum-spin, polarization, superposition

It is easy to collapse a superposition by measuring it.

But how to *induce* a new superposition from a previously collapsed spin or polarization?

1. Electron A is deflected up by an inhomogeneous magnetic field, thus its spin is UP. How might we return it to a state of superposition?
2. Photon B has passed through a vertical polariser, thus the polarization is VERTICAL. How might we return it to a state of superposition?

Comment: Since any state can be expressed as a superposition of some basis states ($\lvert \psi \rangle = \sum\limits_{a^\prime} \lvert a^\prime \rangle\langle a^\prime \vert \psi \rangle$), what exactly do you mean a "state of superposition?"

Comment: @Sandejo i meant experimentally observed "impure" superposition, ie for the electron to again be able to output random outcomes UP and DOWN spin when measured in the same basis, or for the photon to again be able to output  VERTICAL or HORIZONTAL when measured in the same basis?

Comment: @Sandejo may i ask, if you are familiar with sequential Stern-Gerlach experiment, filtering electrons with a particular spin first in the z-direction, followed by the x-direction, then again along z-direction gives a non-zero outcome. Is this theoretically explained by reasoning that the z-direction collapsed spin is actually a superposition in x-direction basis, thus allowing for random spin collapse in the x-direction, which is again actually a superposition in the original z-axis basis, allowing for random spins to be measured again along alternating x-axis and z-axis filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate the spin/polarization $45^o$. Now its state is a combination of vertical and horizontal. Or rotate it any angle. It will be a superposition, though not equal parts.